# Using Dates as params for recursion until 1 date is less than or equal to another date

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to use the following code to loop through 10 days but the dates are not taking.  Any help for what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
     <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/"> 
  <Hi>
    <Start><xsl:value-of select="'Start Here'"/></Start>

    <xsl:call-template name="DayFunction"/>  
    <End><xsl:value-of select="'End Here'"/></End>
</Hi>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="DayFunction">
    <xsl:param name="EndDate" select="2017-05-10"/>
    <xsl:variable name="StartDate" select="2017-05-01"/>


    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$EndDate  >= $StartDate">
            <ok><xsl:value-of select="$EndDate"/></ok>
            <xsl:call-template name="DayFunction">
                <xsl:with-param name="EndDate" select="$EndDate - 1"/>
              </xsl:call-template>  
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
               <ohno><xsl:value-of select="'Stuck   Here'"/></ohno>
           </xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose> 

     </xsl:template> 
     </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please note that I didn't add my xml since I'm really just trying to see why my dates are not comparing and subtracting correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when you do:

```
<xsl:param name="EndDate" select="2017-05-10"/>
```

you have a parameter whose type is *integer* with the value of 2011 (=2017 - 5 - 10). Try defining your parameter as:

```
<xsl:param name="EndDate" select="xs:date('2017-05-10')" />
```

instead.

---

Next, you cannot subtract a number from a date. Instead of:

```
<xsl:with-param name="EndDate" select="$EndDate - 1"/>
```

try:

```
<xsl:with-param name="EndDate" select="$EndDate - xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')"/>
```

---

Working demo: http://xsltransform.net/a9Giwx

Comment: And the lesson you should learn from this is to declare the types of your variables and parameters, e.g. `<xsl:param name=... select=... as="xs:date"/>`. If you had done that, the compiler would have given you an error message and you wouldn't have needed to come here for help.